# how to change background color from one single component in angular

Tags: html, css, angular

I'm building a website where it will have colors alternating between white and black but I can't put background color on the components separately, only on the global CSS. how to solve this?

Comment: Why did you say you can't?

Answer (score 1):

This should be possible in various ways. One is to target the host element in each component's styling file:

```
:host {
  background-color: black;
}
```

To make this dynamic, you could do something clever with a binding or through a global stylesheet, like you've mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways you can do this but I think this is the most simple one.

You can just make two divs

HTML:

```
<div class="black">
</div>
```

And

```
<div class="white">
</div>
```

Then you edit both classes in CSS

You can just do something like this:

```
.black {
   background-color: black;
}

.white {
   background-color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is always better to Use Css file instead of inline coding because it is easy to
spot and change the daata

```html
HTMl
     <div>
          <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 lbl_div ">  
             <label class="title textclr">
               E-MAIL
              </label> 
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 "> 
             <input type="email" id= "email" name="email" class="txtdiv form-                   control" [(ngModel)]="email" required email>
             </div>
      </div>
      
      CSS
      
      .txtdiv {
        margin-top: 1em;
        margin-left: 7em;
        width: 60%;
        height: 2em;
        border-radius: 1em;
        border-color: fuchsia;
        box-shadow: 1px 2px 12px 0px #fff;
        background-color: black
    }
```